# How to use `-webkit-linear-gradient` in non-webkit browsers

Tags: css, webkit

Is it possible to generalise the below to non-webkit browsers? The below css gives something like this which is unfortunately restricted to webkit browsers:

[image]

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 75%, #bbb 75%);
background-size: 30px 30px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 75%, #bbb 75%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 75%, #bbb 75%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 75%, #bbb 75%);
background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #ccc 50%, #ccc 75%, #bbb 75%);
```